# React Native to Django Using Axios [Error: Request failed with status code 400]

Tags: ios, django, react-native, django-rest-framework, axios

I have tried almost all options but not getting through. My Django server is working fine with Postman but when I try it from my React Native app, it gives an error

```
[Error: Request failed with status code 400]
```

My code is:

```
submitData = () => {
        console.log("submitQuestionDataToServer");
        let form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('qOne_img', Platform.OS === 'android' ? photoUri : photoUri.replace('file://', ''));
        form_data.append('qOne_img', Platform.OS === 'android' ? secondPhotoUri : secondPhotoUri.replace('file://', ''));
        form_data.append('question_title', qTitle);
        form_data.append('asked_by', "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/2/");
        let url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/questions/';
        axios.post(url, form_data, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            "Authorization": "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1Nk",
        }
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log("res *******")
              console.log(res.data);
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coz you are sending a string to the image field. The [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) should be a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) type.

it should be something like:

```
const filePath = Platform.OS === 'android' ? photoUri : photoUri.replace('file://', '')
form_data.append('qOne_img',{uri: filePath, type: mimeType, name: fileName} );
```

Not sure the uri is working in react native or not. I use `rn-fetch-blob` for handling blob stuff.

https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob#multipartform-data-example-post-form-data-with-file-and-data

Comment: Code didn't work, but thanks for introducing the rn-fetch-blob library